# Groupby in pandas between rows based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Let's say that I have the following dataframe:

```
   name  number
0     A     100
1     B     200
2     B      30
3     A      20
4     B      30
5     A      40
6     A      50
7     A     100
8     B      10
9     B      20
10    B      30
11    A      40
```

What I would like to do is to merge all the successive rows where `name == 'B'`, between two rows with `name == 'A'` and get the corresponding sum. So, I would like my final output to look like that:

```
    name  number
0    A     100
1    B     230
2    A      20
3    B      30
4    A      40
5    A      50
6    A     100
7    B      60
8    A      40
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use a little groupby trick here.  Create a mask with of `A`'s and then shift each subsequent group of `B`'s into their own group.  This answer assumes that your `name` Series contains *just* A's and B's.

---

```
c = df['name'].eq('A')
m1 = c.cumsum()

m = m1.where(c, m1 + m1.max())

df.groupby(m, sort=False, as_index=False).agg({'name': 'first', 'number': 'sum'})
```

```
  name  number  
0    A     100  
1    B     230  
2    A      20  
3    B      30  
4    A      40  
5    A      50  
6    A     100  
7    B      60  
8    A      40
```

Answer (score 1):

A clumsier attempt - but since I've done it might as well post.

This is just a basic for loop with a while:

```
for i in df.index:
    if i in df.index and df.loc[i, 'name'] == 'B':
        while df.loc[i+1, 'name'] == 'B':
            df.loc[i, 'number'] += df.loc[i+1, 'number']
            df = df.drop(i+1).reset_index(drop=True)
```

It's very straightforward (and hence inefficient I imagine): if B, if next row is also B, add next row to this row's number and delete next row.